# Printing list without square brackets and quotation marks

Tags: python, python-3.x

When entering the following code I get exactly the output I want:

```
entrants = ['a','b','c','d']
# print my list with square brackets and quotation marks
print (entrants)

#print my list without brackets or quotes
#but all on the same line, separated by commas
print(*entrants, sep=", ")

#print my list without brackets or quotes, each element on a different line
#* is known as an 'identifier'
print(*entrants, sep="\n")
```

However when I enter the following code:

```
values = input("Input some comma separated numbers: ")
List = values.split(",")  
Tuple = tuple(List)
print('List : ', List  )
print('Tuple : ', Tuple)  
print('List : ', sep=",", *List  )
print('Tuple : ', sep=",", *Tuple)
```

I get a space and comma before the first values of the last two lines of output as follows:

```
List :  ['1', '2', '3']
Tuple :  ('1', '2', '3')
List : ,1,2,3
Tuple : ,1,2,3
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't think that it would count the initial string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of "sep" in print inserts the separator between the other two arguments.

```
>>> print("a","b",sep="")
ab
```

Try this :

```
>>> def print_sameline():
...     list = [1,2,3]
...     print("List: ",end="")
...     print(*list,sep=",")
... 
>>> print_sameline()
List: 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 0):

using `sep` make the separator go in between all arguments including `'List : '` and `'Tuple : '`, so you should use `.join()` instead to join the List/Tuple with a `","` as the separator:

```
print('List : ', ",".join(List))
print('Tuple : ', ",".join(Tuple))
```